# Filtering images fetched from url by HTML DOM Parsing

Tags: php, html, dom, html-parsing

I am fetching all images from url by HTML DOM like this

```
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
{
  $gimages .= '<img src="';
  $gimages .= $element->src;
  $gimages .= '"width="100"';
  $gimages .= $k;
  $gimages .= '">';
}
```

I am getting all images by above code.But i want to filter exact images that i can show in my web. like 
     http://l.yimg.com/eur.yimg.com/i/any/rebel19.jpg
But sometimes i get invalid path. How can i check the valid image path.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
$handle = fopen("http://l.yimg.com/eur.yimg.com/i/any/rebel19.jpg", "r");

if (!$handle) {
  // file is not present
} else {
  // file present
  // do operation u wnted
}

fclose($handle);
```

This will help you check whether the file is present on that lcation or not